# How to deal with large layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, keras

I'm trying to create a deep learning model with Keras, but when I'm trying make the model, keras uses too much memory.
I'm trying to make a model with a large amount of inputs (24,000) and it seems too much for my computer.

Here is my simple code:

```
N=20
M=5
n = 24310
nbclass = 4 

X_train = np.random.rand(N,n)
X_test = np.random.rand(M,n)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(nbclass, size=N), nbclass)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(nbclass, size=M), nbclass)


model.add(Dense(n, input_dim=n, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) 
model.add(Dense(n//2,  activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))  
model.add(Dense(nbclass,activation="softmax", kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Compiling the model 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fitting the model 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),epochs=100, batch_size=5,callbacks=[PlotLosses()])
```

My issue here is, when the fit is done, it consumes all my memory (20 Go), then it starting to swap and I cannot go further.
Somebody knows how can I modify the model to make it less memory consuming?

Comment: do you really have 8pieces of data with 24310 features?

Comment: And you want to validate it with 2 samples?

Comment: No, I have more but it just for the example. The issue is I cannot fit the model even with that small dataset.

Comment: And with batchsize of 10, something wrong with this, I think.

Comment: Could you give more information about, why is your feature number is so huge to help answer your question?

Comment: Ok I increase the number of verctors to 20 for the training set and 5 for the test set. I decrease the batch size to 5. But I get the same issue.

Comment: The problem not that parameters, but the feature number i.e. 24310

Comment: Just trying to help you.

Comment: My vector feature is coming from a connectivity matrices which are 221 by 221. As those matrices are symmetrical I only get the data over the diagonal as my features. My goal is to make a classification of those connectivity matrices.

Comment: Can you solve this via convolution?

Comment: I think their might be some chance that your connectivity matrices carries spatial information. In this case you can use convolutional layers and consume less memory.

Comment: How can I modify the layers to include convolution? the connectivity matrices are quite sparse so I don't know if convolution is pertinent here.

Comment: but it's worth trying

Comment: Alternatively you can crop the tensors/matrices into smaller parts, then giving them the same label. If now spatial information they have.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your idea to crop the vectors?

Comment: You talked about 221 by 221 matrix too. I don't want to give false advice as I didn't see into the original problem, but if you wanted to use Dense layers, you can do it by splitting the matrices in one dimension and send through a more narrow Dense layer with the same label at training phase. Then if you want to classify the whole matrix in one you can send its splitted parts (vectors) in a batch, then average the results.

Comment: I see. Yes, that a good idea. I will also try that.

Comment: I would be happy if you would inform me about developments, I'm really wondering about results.

Comment: It came across my mind that, if you have a sparse vector, actually it can be enough perhaps much less neuron in the first and second layer resulting in much less parameters, so GB as well. Just a guess.